# Need CSS Box/Grid layout advice

Tags: css, layout, grid, css-position, box

**UPDATED**  ... Here is my latest code.

1. Now need some way to place the Button MIDDLE or BOTTOM (vertically).
2. As a complete newbie, I would welcome any other comments about the
   code used here.

:) ...  cheers

```css
     
*  html {
 font:   2em Georgia, sans-serif; 
 color:  #7b7b7b;
 clear:  both;
 float:  justify;
}

body {
 margin: 0.5em 4.0em 0.5em 4.0em;
 padding: 1.0em 4.0em 1.0em 4.0em;
 width: 55.0em;
 height: auto;
 background-color: tan;
}
.imgclass {
 border: 0.15em solid yellow;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1.0em;
    grid-template-columns: 75% 25%;
    grid-template-areas:
   "header  header"
   "picture  button"
   "article  article"
   "footer  footer";
    background: tan;
 margin-top: 2.0em;
 margin-left: 1.0em;
    color: teal;
 width: 100%;
    }

.box {
 color: white;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
 padding: 0 2.0em 0 2.0em;
 margin: 0 0 0 1.0em;
}

.header {
 grid-area: header;
 position: relative; 
 margin-left: 1.0em;
 padding-left: 1.0em;
 border: 1.0em;
 border-color: white;
 height: auto;
}

.picholder {
 grid-template-columns: 1 -1;
 grid-template-rows: 2 3;
 margin: 0;
}

.picture {
 grid-area: picture;
 grid-template-columns: 2;
 grid-template-rows: 3;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 0;
 border-left: 0;
} 

.button {
 grid-area: button;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 1.0em;
 background: #3498db;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #11828a);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #11828a);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #11828a);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #11828a);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #11828a);
 -webkit-border-radius: 1.0em;
 -moz-border-radius: 1.0em;
 width: 12.0em;
 border-radius: 1.0em;
 font-family: Georgia;
 color: #c4db14;
 font-size: 1.0em;
 padding: 0.7em 1.0em 0.7em 1,0em;
 border: solid #96d60b 0.2em;
 text-decoration: none;
} 
.button:hover {
 background: #fc3c63;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fc3c63, #91092b);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fc3c63, #91092b);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fc3c63, #91092b);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fc3c63, #91092b);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fc3c63, #91092b);
 text-decoration: none;
} 
.button:active {
 background-color: #3e8e41;
 box-shadow: 0 0.1em #666;
 transform: translateY(0.2em);
} 

.article {
 grid-area: article;
   grid-template-columns: 1 -1;
 grid-template-rows: 4;
 position: relative;
 background: coral;
 margin: 0 0 0 2.0em;;
 padding:1.0em 1.0em 1.0em 2.0em;  
}

.footer {
 grid-area: footer; 
 background-color: maroon;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 height: 2.0em;
}



h1 { 
 font-size: 1.0em; 
 color: blue; 
 margin: 0;
}
h2 { 
 font-size: 0.75em; 
 color: white; 
 margin: 1.0em;
}
h3 { 
 font-size: 1.2em; 
 text-align: center;
 color: white; 
 margin: 0;
}
t1 { font: 400 100px/1.3 'Berkshire Swash', sans-serif; 
 color: red; 
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fdfdfd 4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); 
 font-style: italic; 
 font-weight: 600;
 background: grey;
}
t2 {  
font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif; 
color: black; 
text-align: center;
font-size: 0.6em; 
margin: 0.2em;
padding: 0.2em;
}

a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; 
}
a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; 
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>TestSite >>> ProPokerUK ... testIndex.html ... testCSS.css</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Georgia' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/reset.css" >  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/testCSS.css" >
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="box header">
  <t1>&nbsp;ProPokerUK &nbsp;</t1>
 </div>
 <div class="box picholder">
  <div class="picture">
   <img class="imgclass" src="images/pp-img1.jpg" width="650px" alt="images/pp-img1.jpg" />
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="button"><h3>Change Picture</h3></div>
 
 <div class="box article">
  <p><h1>Under Construction</h1>  
   <h2><br/>If you need to you can  &nbsp; <a href="mailto:webman@propokeruk.co.uk?Subject=ProPokerUK.co.uk website enquiry">contact us</a> &nbsp; by email. &nbsp; &nbsp;
    &nbsp; Otherwise we shall be online soon !  </h2>
  </p>
 </div>

 <div class="box footer">
  <p>  <t2>&nbsp;  copyright &nbsp; &#169ProPokerUK, 2017 &nbsp;</t2> </p>
 </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't see any element actually using the `.article` class. Is it missing? Also you have a lot of minor misspellings in your code. Such as missing an ending bracket at a `<h1`. And the `<t1>` and `<t2>` tags should probably be `<h1>` and `<h2>`. In addition to this `&nbsp;` to align text should be avoided. Use CSS paddings and other ways to position your elements. Try running your site through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org) :o)

Comment: Have managed to find HTML-kit TOOLS.   ...
 Some silly mistakes left in the CSS code,  but it also says "Grid-template-..." and "Grid-area" not recognised. ... 
Would like advice on the padding/margins on left side of picture (to line up with rest of the page.  .... 
Also need to get the button placed to the right and near the bottom of the picture.  
Can repeat or answer the query with updated code ?